# Aligning an icon and a title to the baseline

Tags: html, css

I'm building a responsive website and I want the behavior in this picture:
[image]

The bottom edge of the icon (the baseline) is aligned with the bottom edge of the title but I wasn't able to do that in a responsive way. Here is what I've tried:

- add the `position: relative` to the parent and the `position: absolute` to the icon and changed the location with `left` and `right` and `bottom`. That worked but it isn't responsive (the position of the icon changes on different screen sizes).
- add `vertical align: text-bottom` to both of them (the icon and the title) but that doesn't work either
- add `display: block` to the icon and `left: 0` and `right: 0` to center the icon. That worked and I added a padding right in order to position the icon in front of the title. It works when I toggle the device toolbar:

**When I decrease the viewport width:**

[image]

**When I toggle to the device toolbar:**

[image]

The problem is, as seen above, the icon and the title are not aligned to the baseline. I tried to add `display: inline-block` to have the powers of the `padding-bottom` and the `margin-bottom` but that also didn't work. I hope you can help me.

Here is my code in a snippet:

```css
body {
  background-color: purple;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  height: 6rem;
  background-color: red;
  transition: height .1s;
}

.container-add {
  height: 21rem;
}

.hamburger-btn {
  position: absolute;
  right: 4px;
  font-size: 40px;
  color: white;
  margin-top: 33px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.logo-box {
  display: inline-block;
}

.logo {
  width: 50%;
  margin-left: 1.2rem;
  margin-top: .8rem
}

.main-nav {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 13.62rem;
  align-items: center;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.main-nav-hide {
  visibility: visible;
}

.main-nav-item {
  list-style: none;
  color: white;
  font-family: Roboto;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 700;
  /* display: none; */
}

.main-nav-link {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
  padding-left: 20px;
}

.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 55vh;
  position: relative;
}

.imgSlide {
  width: 100%;
  height: 53vh;
}

.imgSlide-show {
  display: block;
}

.dotz {
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 3vh;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
}

.dot {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #ddd
}

.active {
  background-color: #ff9900;
}

.active:hover,
.dot:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.fade-zz {
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.4s;
  transition: .4s
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {
    opacity: .4;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1
  }
}

.contact-box {
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
  top: -1rem;
  height: 380px;
}

.conbox {
  color: white;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 2rem;
  /* margin-top: .8rem; */
}

.adress {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: roboto;
  margin-bottom: 3rem;
  position: relative;
  top: .5rem;
}

.phone {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: roboto;
  margin-bottom: .8rem;
}

.opening-time {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: roboto;
  margin-top: 2rem;
}

.about-us {
  color: black;
  font-family: Roboto;
  position: relative;
}

.title {
  text-align: center;
}

.abicon {
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 2rem;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding-right: 130px;
  margin: auto;
}

.title-description {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="logo-box">
    <img src="images/logo.png" class="logo" alt="logo">
  </div>
  <i class="fas fa-bars hamburger-btn"></i>
  <ul class="main-nav">
    <li class="main-nav-item"><a class="main-nav-link" href="#">services</a></li>
    <li class="main-nav-item"><a class="main-nav-link" href="#">reservation</a></li>
    <li class="main-nav-item"><a class="main-nav-link" href="#">menu</a></li>
    <li class="main-nav-item"><a class="main-nav-link" href="#">our chefs</a></li>
    <li class="main-nav-item"><a class="main-nav-link" href="#">events</a></li>
  </ul>

</div>

<div class="slideshow-container">
  <div class="mySlides fade-zz">
    <img src="images/food3.png" class="imgSlide">
  </div>
  <div class="mySlides fade-zz">
    <img src="images/pizza.png" class="imgSlide">
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade-zz">
    <img src="images/hamburger2.png" class="imgSlide">
  </div>

  <div class="dotz">
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1-1)"></span>
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2-1)"></span>
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3-1)"></span>
  </div>


</div>





<div class="contact-box">
  <div class="adress">
    <i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt conbox"></i>
    <h3 class="contact-title">Address</h3>
    <p class="contact-description">4579 Penn Street,Manchester<br>united kingdom</p>
  </div>
  <div class="phone">
    <i class="fas fa-phone-volume conbox"></i>
    <h3 class="contact-title">Phone</h3>
    <p class="contact-description">636-399-9776 <br> 573-225-7350</p>
  </div>
  <div class="opening-time">
    <i class="far fa-clock conbox"></i>
    <h3 class="contact-title">Opening time</h3>
    <p class="contact-description">all the days of the week <br>from 6 am to midnight</p>
  </div>
</div>

<section class="about-us">
  <i class="fas fa-utensils abicon"></i>
  <h1 class="title">About us</h1>
  <p class="title-description">Le Lorem Ipsum est simplement du faux texte employé dans la composition et la mise en page avant impression. Le Lorem Ipsum est le faux texte standard de l'imprimerie depuis les années 1500, quand un imprimeur anonyme assembla </p>
</section>
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Don't just post all your code. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and rework your question.

Comment: One problem I can see is that you repeatedly tried something, and then tried something else without removing the first thing you tried!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to move the icon with class `"abicon"` inside the `<h1>`, just before the text. Then you can remove all styles from the `.abicon` selector.

(Note that in this snippet, I removed all the unnecessary elements, so that you can see what happens better.)

```css
.about-us {
  color: black;
  font-family: Roboto;
  position: relative;
}

.title {
  text-align: center;
}

.abicon {
  /*
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 2rem;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding-right: 130px;
  margin: auto;
  */
}

.title-description {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,700" rel="stylesheet">

<section class="about-us">
  <h1 class="title"><i class="fas fa-utensils abicon"></i> About us</h1>
  <p class="title-description">Le Lorem Ipsum est simplement du faux texte employé dans la composition et la mise en page avant impression. Le Lorem Ipsum est le faux texte standard de l'imprimerie depuis les années 1500, quand un imprimeur anonyme assembla </p>
</section>
```